# What is the adjective of "Platz"?

Tags: adjective

Is there an adjective of "Platz"?
As there is one for e.g.

> "Haus" --> "häuslich"
>
> "Stadt" --> "städtisch"
>
> "Raum" --> "Räumlich"

I am looking for the ›right‹ term of "inner-platziale Untersuchung" which (should) mean that only the "Platz" is considered for further analysis not its close environment.

Comment: There isn't one as there isn't one for "Straße" either but you may use *örtlich* if it matches what you want to say.

Comment: Da dein Vorname kein C sondern ein K enthält, und weil du laut Profil in Berlin wohnst, glaube ich, dass du Deutscher bist, und das Deutsch deine Muttersprache ist. Du bist hier in einem Deutsch-Forum, in dem Fragen über die deutsche Sprache beantwortet werden. Was glaubst du ist die Muttersprache der meisten Antwort-Autoren in diesem Forum? Richtig: Deutsch. Wenn nun also jemand, der Deutsch spricht, eine Frage über die deutsche Sprache stellt, und annehmen kann, dass deutsche Muttersprachler sie beantworten werden: In welcher Frage sollte man die Frage dann stellen? Englisch? Wohl eher nicht

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich antworte auf Deutsch, weil du offenbar Deutscher bist, und dies hier ein Deutsch-Forum ist.

Warum glaubst du, dass es ein solches Adjektiv geben würde? Zu den Nomen *Hütte*, *City*, *Areal*, *Straße*, *Gasse*, usw. gibt es auch keine Adjektive. Dass es zu einem Nomen ein Adjektiv gibt, ist eher die Ausnahme als die Regel.

Du musst eben eine andere Formulierung finden, z.B.:

> Untersuchung innerhalb des Platzes

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort - da ich mich sonst nur in den technischen Foren herumtreibe, habe ich die Frage wie sonst dort üblich auf Englisch gestellt. Ich hatte mich gefragt, ob ich das entsprechende Adjektiv nicht kenne oder ob es das nicht gibt, bzw. was wäre ein geeigneter Neologismus?

Answer (score 3):

Für den Kontext, der in der Frage angedeutet wurde, ginge vielleicht:

> eine platzbezogene Untersuchung
>
> eine Platzuntersuchung

Nicht supertoll vielleicht, aber da eben Wörter gesucht wurden, darunter auch neue...